# Where have my 125 GB free space gone?

Tags: network, finder, hard-drive

I have a Mac Mini server (macOS Sierra, 10.12.6) with a RAID 1 hard disk, which (when I Screen Share into it) has 716 GB of free space:

[image]

However, when I connect to the disk via File Sharing from my laptop (macOS High Sierra, 10.13.3), it says there's only 591 GB left. What causes Finder to report 125 GB free space less than on the machine itself?

[image]

Comment: Check the purgeable part of the available free space (cmd-i > RAID)! I assume it's ~125 GB.

Comment: @klanomath right, spot on. The next question is why macOS thinks it can purge 125 GB to my 5 GB iCloud account ... but I need to post that as a new question, I think.

Comment: This is an Apple secret... ;-)